# Action class is not locatable in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/alcodesmobility/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://www.browserstack.com/");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Get started free"));

        action.moveToElement(element).click();
        //using click action method
    }
}
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23
> (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294})
> on port 24715 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully. [1622542783.292][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver
> has not been tested with Chrome version 90. Jun 01, 2021 3:49:43 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
> Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to class
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable
> (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement and
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable are in unnamed
> module of loader 'app')   at
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.moveToElement(Actions.java:387)
> at CronberrySignin.test.main(test.java:22)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing completing the move to element code line.
Try this instead:

```
action.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement Actions class, the element is in Selenium viewport right from the page loading.

use **id** instead.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("signupModalButton")).click();
```

Read when to use actions class [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

and by reading **exception stack trace,** it looks like driver issue. Make sure to use `inline version of Selenium webdriver`, `chromedriver`, and `chrome broswer`.

Comment: Actually, I've to use Action class for drag and drop but the above code I have written just to test the action class since it wasn't working in the original code, where I need to implement the same.

Comment: You need to use `action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();` and the reason is this When you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are stored in a queue in the ActionChains object. When you call perform(), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

Comment: I've tried it but getting the same error class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement and org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
 at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.moveToElement(Actions.java:387)